Approximation using polynomials with integer coefficients
The classic Weierstrass Theorem states that the set of polynomials are dense in $C[0,1]$ equipped with $|| \cdot ||_{\infty}$. Bernstein's proof of Weierstrass Theorem gives an explicit form of polynomials that approximate a given function $f \in C[0,1]$.
$$B_n^f(x) := \sum_{k=0}^n f(\frac kn) \binom nk x^k (1-x)^{n-k}.$$
If we want to approximate a function by using polynomials of integer coefficients, we must have $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are both integers. Otherwise, $||f - p||_\infty \ge \varepsilon >0$ for all polynomials $p$ with integer coefficients.
My question is if the converse is true, that is, if $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are both integers, then can we approximate $f$ by a sequence $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of polynomials with integer coefficients, $||p_n - f||_\infty \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
This can be reduced to the case that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.
Assuming the statement is true for all $f \in C[0,1]$ with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.
Given $g \in C[0,1]$ with $g(0) = a, g(1) = b$ both integers, we can approximate $f(x) = g(x) - (b-a)x - a$ by a sequence $\{p_n\}$ with integer coefficients by assumption, since $f(0) = g(0) - a = 0$ and $f(1) = g(1) - b = 0$.
Then $g(x)$ can be approximated by $p_n +(b-a)x + a$.

It seems this is a theorem of I. Chlodovsky from 1925.  I found a reference to it here.  Chlodovsky's paper "Une remarque sur la representation des fonctions continues par
des polynomes a coefficients entiers", Math. Sb., 32(3):472–475, 1925,  is here

I think I overthought this problem. We may directly consider the integral polynomial $$p_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor f(\frac kn) \binom nk \rfloor x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$$
where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the integer part function.
Fix $\varepsilon > 0$, for sufficiently large $n$, we have (i) $|| f - B_n^f||_{\infty} < \varepsilon /2$, and (ii) $\frac1n < \varepsilon /2$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - p_n(x)| & \le |f(x) - B_n^f(x)| + |B_n^f(x) - p_n(x)| \\
& \le \frac\varepsilon 2 + \sum_{k=0}^n (f(\frac nk) \binom nk - \lfloor f(\frac nk)\binom nk \rfloor ) x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \\
& \le \frac\varepsilon 2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \text{  where $f(0) = f(1) = 0$,} \\
& \le \frac\varepsilon 2 + \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom nk x^k (1-x)^{n-k}  \text{  where $\frac1n \binom nk \ge 1$ for $k \ne 0,n$.}\\
& \le \frac\varepsilon 2 + \frac 1n (x + 1-x)^n \\
& < \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $p_n$ converges to $f$ w.r.t. $|| \cdot ||_{\infty}$ and $p_n$ is a sequence of polynomials with integer coefficients.
